# Container with different sized (resolution) pictures all fitting together

Tags: html, css, image, dynamic, containers

I have this current code:

**CSS:**

```
img
{
    max-width:15vw;
    max-height:15vh;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#67615d;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:justify;
}

#container 
{
    width:80%;
    min-height:100vh;
    margin:0px;
    float:right;
    margin:0px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}

#navbar
{
 background-color:#67615d;
 width:20%;
 height:100vh;
 overflow:hidden;  
 position:fixed;
 float:left;
}



#content 
{
      width:100vw;
      min-height:100vh;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      overflow:hidden; 
      background-color:#9d948f;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">


<div id="navbar">
*stuff in the navbar*      
</div>


<div id="container">
</div><img src="pic1"></img>
</div><img src="pic2"></img>
</div><img src="pic3"></img>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, with this as my current code (add a few more things) and it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mLct.jpg

These pics are just random screenshots and the others are random pictures (obviously just for testing purposes, the real thing will have pictures of all resolutions) I got off of google. Anyway, what I am trying to do is automatically adjust the pictures so that they all fit within the container while being different sizes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQCwW.png

The black boxes are the "pictures", this is what I am trying to do but I keep messing up here and there, does anyone know how I would change my code to display the pictures as such?
Any advice or answers would be greatly appreciated :D!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a javascript masonry layout for this:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Follow the docs and it's an easy install.